# javascript overriding not working in production

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

in my app i want to override a js file which is already available in gem . now problem is i m able to override it in development and its working properly also

but in production its calling js file from gem not from my app
   my app

```
if (city!='' && state!='') {
    $('#Location').val(city+', '+state).removeClass('defaultTextActive');
}
```

gem

```
if (city!='' && state!=''&& pin!='') {
    $('#Location').val(city+', '+state+','+pin).removeClass('defaultTextActive');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this out

clear all your precompiled assets, and regenerate them with following rake tasks.

```
  rake assets:clean
  rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

Comment: hi  im getting bellow error when try rake assets:clean  /home/swagata/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby /home/swagata/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/bin/rake assets:clean:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets  i tried to install  gem install activerecord-postrgesql-adapter
getting error like ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'activerecord-postrgesql-adapter' (>= 0) in any repository

rake aborted!
Please install the postegresql adapter: `gem install activerecord-postegresql-adapter` (cannot load such file -- active_record/connection_adapters/postegresql_adapter)